# Matlab - object orientated with abstract Interface - How creating object?

Tags: matlab, object

Hello lovely community,

i am quite new here, but still hope someone can help me out. I just worked a bit with Matlab in the past and want to do a new project. Earlier I just stored all in one Matlab file and didn't had the need to use classes. This has changed now, so I hope someone can explain me what I did wrong.

My desire is to create the project object based. Therefore I started creating new folders in the main folder:

```
C:\Users\Luftfahrt\MAV\
```

The folder names are:

```
+Data
+Model
```

After I read the first chapters of

> A guide to MATLAB orientaded programming

I figured out that with the plus symbol I am creating public objects. Exactly as I want. In each folder I inserted an abstract Interface and a child for it.

```
DataLoaderIF

classdef DataLoaderIF< handle

methods (Abstract=true)
    Data = LoadData(Asset,Start,End)
    Status = getStatus(Obj)
    Info = getInfo(Obj)
end

end
```

When i run this code above he is telling me that Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but I did it exactly as in the book. Maybe I thought, it is stupid run code from an abstract interface, so that there is no problem, is that true?

```
DataLoader

classdef DataLoader < DataManager.DataLoaderIF
    %Inheritent from DataLoaderIF. Is setting parameter and Importing

    properties (Access=protected)
        mStatus =-1; %nothing done
        mInfo ='Import'; %
        mData; %saving the imported data
        mCollector; %to save the prices after structuring
    end

    methods  
        %creating the constructor
        function Obj = DataManager

        function getStatus(Obj)

            mStatus=1;
        end

        function getInfo(Obj)

            Info='Import';
            mInfo= Info;
        end

    function LoadData(Asset,Start,End)
        connection = yahoo;
        mData= fetch(connection, Asset, Start,End, 'd');
        close(connection)
        %'JPY=X', '01-Jun-2011', datestr(now,'dd-mmm-yyyy'), 'd');
        mCollector= [{'date' 'open' 'high' 'low' 'close' 'volume' 'adj-close'}
            cellstr(datestr(mData(:,1))) num2cell(mData(:,2:end))];
    end
end
```

What I wanted to do now is to create an Object and then give this Object the variables to perform the fetch. But how can I instantiate now the Object? He says my constructor is false.

Someone has some ideas?

P.S. I already looked here [Documentation Matlab](http://de.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2012a/techdoc/matlab_oop/brgxk22-1.html?searchHighlight=abstract), but this didn't help me out.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: is it a typo or are you missing an `end` to your constructor function ?

Comment: I just thought when I am writing one line code, that this end is not necessary? Am I wrong?
Just added it, still cant instantiate an Object :(

Comment: Is DataManager an abstract class? Also, could you explain the hierarchy a bit better? I have trouble to understand why you inherit from DataLoaderIF and then use the DataManager constructor.

Comment: Looks like you're missing an "end" in your methods block as well.  Also, shouldn't LoadData take "obj" as the first argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you want to do exactly and why you need an abstract class then a derived one, but assuming you really need all that for more purpose than you described, take the following into account:

- By definition in OOP, an abstract class **cannot** be instantiated. It is only a basic framework for the different classes which will inherit from it, and you can only instantiate these inheriting classes. abstract classes are only useful if the different inheriting classes represent different objects but need to share a set of (almost) common methods. If not, forget the 'abstract' parent and just design the class that does what you need.
- Be careful with the classes which inherit from the `handle` class. In Matlab they behave differently than the `value` classes. Read [this article](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html) and decide which type you want.
- If you decide to use a `handle` class, consider the following very important factor [Initialising property value](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/specifying-properties.html#br18hyr):

> Initializing Properties to Unique Values
>
> MATLAB assigns properties to the specified default values only once
>   when MATLAB loads the class definition. Therefore, if you initialize a
>   property value with a handle-class constructor, MATLAB calls this
>   constructor only once and every instance references the same handle
>   object. If you want a property value to be initialized to a new
>   instance of a handle object each time you create an object, assign the
>   property value in the constructor.

---

Now with all that in mind, below is a version of your class that does run, and that you can instantiate as below:

```
>> dl = DataLoader
dl = 
  DataLoader with no properties.
>> dl.getInfo
ans =
Import
>> dl.getStatus
ans =
    -1
>> dl.LoadData(1,2,3) %// etc ...
```

The class definition is as follow

```
classdef DataLoader < DataLoaderIF

    properties (Access=protected)
        mStatus         %// nothing done
        mInfo           %//
        mData           %// saving the imported data
        mCollector      %// to save the prices after structuring
    end

    methods
        %// Constructor (and initialise default value). For classes which
        %// inherit from the "handle" class it is very important to
        %// intialise your default values IN THE CONSTRUCTOR, and NOT in
        %// the property definition.
        function obj = DataLoader
            obj.mStatus = -1 ;
            obj.mInfo = 'Import' ;
            obj.mData = [] ;
            obj.mCollector = [] ;
        end

        function Status = getStatus(obj)
            Status = obj.mStatus ;
        end

        function Info = getInfo(obj)
            %// a "get" type of function should not assign value, only
            %// return information about the object.
            Info = obj.mInfo ;
        end

        %// the "obj" parameter has to be the first parameter of the
        %// function in it's signature.
        function LoadData(obj,Asset,Start,End)
            %// Put function help here

            %// I don't know what this part of the code is supposed to do
            %// so I leave it as it is. Be aware that the fucntion "fetch"
            %// will have to be accessible in your context or the function
            %// will error
            connection = 'yahoo' ;
            obj.mData = fetch(connection, Asset, Start , End, 'd') ;
            close(connection)
            obj.mCollector= [{'date' 'open' 'high' 'low' 'close' 'volume' 'adj-close'}
                cellstr(datestr(obj.mData(:,1))) num2cell(obj.mData(:,2:end))];

            %// Here do your own test with your own conditions to decide
            %// what the status of the object should be.
            if ~isempty(obj.mData) && ~isempty(obj.mCollector)
                obj.Status = 1 ;
            end

        end
    end
end
```

---

You seemed a bit confused on some concept of OOP. If your first contact with OOP is through Matlab I totally understand where you come from. I had the same experience and my understanding of OOP was wrong for many years (my OOP code was very poor and inefficient too as a result), until I properly learned my way in `C++` and `.Net`. These last two languages are real OOP languages (*I know, not the only ones, or even better one, I don't want to start a debate*), in the sense that you need to understand the OOP concepts to get anything out of them. On the other hand, you can spend your life doing wonderful things on Matlab and remain blissfully unaware of what even OOP means.

OOP capability was introduced in Matlab as a "convenience" for programmers who missed this way of structuring their code. The first implementations were very clunky and unpractical (*raise your hand if you remember having to code each and every one of your* `subassign`, `subsref`, `display`, `get`, `set`  etc *for each single object !!*). It has been drastically improved since then, until it is now something worth the extra coding effort if you want to get the benefit of OOP organisation (code reuse, polymorphism, inheritance etc ...). However, to this day the OOP syntax in Matlab remain un-instinctive at first even for OOP veterans (*why the hell do we have to declare the object itself as the first parameter of the function, is the compiler so blind it does't see the function is in the class definition?*). You just have to get used to it first, then it gets ok.
The Matlab documentation on OOP is mostly oriented to these veterans. It explains to people who knows OOP on another languages how to apply the concepts in the Matlab specific syntax. It is not at all a very good guide for pure beginners.

This (*longer than I wanted, sorry*) blurb, was to try to explain that:

- If you need to learn OOP concepts, train yourself with another language first. (seriously, even with the learning curve of learning another language, you'll loose less time than with the trial and error approach on Matlab).
- If you do not have a definite identified **need** for OOP code in Matlab, do not insist. You can do a lot of things (in fact almost everything) in Matlab without resorting to classes (at least not knowingly, of course you will use the base Matlab classes in the background, but you can use and maintain your car for many years without necessarily having an intimate knowledge of its every component).

Comment: Thanks so far! I just got back home and now I am working myself through your code! Already a huge thanks. This will help me a lot! I am going to answer you more in detail when I implemented it and did progress due to your help!

Comment: I just implemented your suggestions and thanks already for your work. You found exactly what I was looking for and understood my question. But unfortunately I still have some problems. I implemented like you suggested, but I am getting the following error message: `Undefined function or variable 'DataLoader'.` 
The program should be scalable and therefore OOP is needed. I am going to get some C++ books to improve my skills, but time is short and so I hope to improve with Matlab already. I used the same notation like [here](http://de.mathworks.com/cmsimages/64515_wl_91545v01_obj_fig2_wl.gif)

Comment: I am not allowed to write more than 600 characters so here the rest of the answer! I already looked for literature and found two promising books, the one mentioned in my question, but with object orientated programming and abstract classes they didn't handle. The hint with handle and where to initiliate the values is really helpful, didn't know that!
What is really strange is, that after executing the code i get an object, but this is called ans and not obj. How can I change the name of the resulting object?

Comment: your object will be called by the variable name you use the first time you instantiate it (the first time you call the constructor). So if you type `dl = DataLoader` you will have in your workspace an instance of your object called `dl`. If you call the constructor without assigning it a name (like simply `DataLoader`), Matlab will assign the object returned in the default variable always called `ans`. (`ans` is short for `answer`). `ans` will always be used to store the result of the last operation in the console if you do not specify a result variable (try to type `2+3` in your console ...)

Comment: Hello Hoki, thanks again for helping me out. I didn't read your post yesterday and just have seen it now. So sorry for the delay. That i have to give my function a return variable make sense and is similar as I have learnt it with Java. But when I try to run dl = DataLoader he is telling me that 'Undefined function or variable `DataLoader'`. I don't understand it, because normally he should know this variable because it is the name of my `classdef`or do I missing something? I implemented the code like you have suggested, but get always this error message... altready added it to the path...

Comment: Do you have an idea why this is so? I would lovely upvote your post, but stackoverflow is telling me that I don't have the reputation to do so! So I am sorry, that I am not able to upvote your answer and also neither your comments. But let say in at this point, I am really glad and thankful that you help me out!
It is interesting. The autoflfilling function in Matlab works. So when I type `dl = DataL`he adds with `Tabulator`the value `dl = DataLoader` but still the same error message as above...

Comment: I just found the error. Finally! I am not quite sure what the problem was, but I assume that I was in the wrong path and therefore Matlab couldn't execute it properly. Now I can execute it as I want! Thanks!!!!

Comment: "why the hell do we have to declare the object itself as the first parameter of the function"?  I'd bet it's because Mathworks didn't want to reserve a new keyword like `this` or `self` to refer to instance data (which is also why I think it is a `classdef` instead of a `class`) while also making the distinction between global functions (since the most used Matlab functions are in a flat, global namespace) and class methods explicit.